# How to make a website-wide footer using <div>

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to make a footer appear by just using

```
<div class="footer"></div>
```

on all pages linked up to a js file that lets you change it on all pages without having to go through them?

I'm quite new to JS and I was wondering if this was the correct way to go

```
    document.write('\
\
    <p>Created by Lewis Milburn</p>\
\
');
```

Comment: you might want to look into single page applications

Comment: it's for my html based website, i know a bit just not everything about js

Comment: You can use an iframe and and have the footer be another page. I did it before with php and just included the footer that way. `<div class="footer"><?php include footer.php ?></div>`

Comment: That's assuming he's using php though

Comment: I would not like to use iframe because it messes up the page layout a bit

Comment: And no, i'm not using PHP

Comment: @Brian which is why I said use and iframe. I was showing an example on how I did it though.

Comment: @LewisMilburn You will have to play with the CSS a bit for it to look how you want it. You can also go the JavaScript route. `document.write('insertFooter()');`. You would then have a JS file that you would include on every page that contact the `insertFooter` function that would return the text to write. And anything you changed in the JS file would change across all pages.

Comment: You don't really need to add "(Answered)" to the title. :P  Just click the checkmark next to the answer that best resolves your question after the 15 minutes it requires you to wait.

Comment: I agree with Joseph, if your question is in fact answered wait the allotted time frame to accept an answer and mark it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to play with the CSS a bit for it to look how you want it. You can also go the JavaScript route `document.write('insertFooter()');`. You would then have a JS file that you would include on every page that contact the insertFooter function that would return the text to write. And anything you changed in the JS file would change across all pages.

Example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4s8hfc4c/)

```
function insertFooter(){
    var htmlToReturn = "<p>Created by Loaf</p>";

  return htmlToReturn;
}

var footer = document.getElementById("footer");
footer.innerHTML = insertFooter();
```

The function `insertFooter` would be in another file, instead of how my Fiddle is.

One thing I want to add is that some users can have JavaScript disabled in their browser, and you may also have a small flicker where the footer isn't being displayed when you first load the page, because we are loading it via JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

For something simple, I suppose you can do something like this:

```
//scripts.js
function showFooter() {
    var footer = document.getElementById("footer");
    footer.classList.remove("hidden")
}

showFooter();
```

Then for the HTML file:

```
...
<div id="footer" class="hidden">
    <p>Created by Lewis Milburn</p>
</div>

<style>
    .hidden {
        display: none
    }
</style>
...
```

Then use something like this right before the closing body tag to remove the hidden class:

```
<script src="./scripts.js"></script>
```

What happens here is that soon as you reference the scripts.js file, showFooter() is run and it will remove the hidden class. Here is a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/cafusotide/edit?html,css,js,output) for you.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the issue where he can change the footer on all of his pages by editing just one file.

Comment: Good call, missed that bit. Modifying it